# How do I get TimeSpan given a date and a time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

Is it possible to get the timespan of A and B, where A(MM-dd-yyyy) = `10-06-2015 23:45` and B = `9:00 AM`. The given format of data are exactly what it is on this post. I guess am having trouble on formatting, no coded work yet.

I have other question that may linked to the first, is `if(A>B)` possible ? where A(MM-dd-yyyy) = `10-06-2015 23:45` and B = `9:00 AM`. Does comparing the two data possible ?

Comment: Are you asking for the *difference* between A and B?  What if B is on a different date than A? What if it's already passed? Would you expect a negative value, or the next day?  Do you need it to consider daylight saving time, and if so - in the local time zone or in an arbitrary time zone?  Please edit your question to be more specific.  A few examples of input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: thank you for the tip, sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact( "10-06-2015 23:45"  , "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"   , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
DateTime b = DateTime.ParseExact( "10-06-2015 9:00 AM", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
TimeSpan difference = a - b;
```

If you only know `b` by the time-of-day, then this works:

```
DateTime b = DateTime.ParseExact( "9:00 AM" "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
b = a.Date.Add( b.TimeOfDay );

TimeSpan difference = a - b;
```

You say you're using `DateTimePicker`, in which case:

```
DateTime a = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime b = a.Date.Add( dateTimePicker2.TimeOfDay );
TimeSpan difference = a - b;
```

Comment: but, my B's format is fixed as 9:00 AM from DateTime Picker

Comment: @SuperPruuylan my apologies. I have expanded my answer to include that scenario.

Comment: @SuperPruuylan That said, if you're using `DateTimePicker` then you don't need `ParseExact` at all, you can use the value directly. I'll update my answer.

Comment: let me ask you something, my A = `10-06-2015 23:45` and B = `9:00 AM`. Is it possible, sir, to do this `if(A >B)` ? sorry, I can't tag yah name

Comment: @SuperPruuylan You can, but `B` must consist of a date and time value, not just a time value. Look at my code to see how I'm adding the date component of `a` to the time component of the time-of-day value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) for this.

[This](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.in/2007/06/understanding-datetime-and-timespan-in.html) will also help.

Example: Define your times like this.

`startDate='10-06-2015'
 startTime=10-06-2015 23:45:00 AM'`

```
TimeSpan ts = startTime.TimeOfDay;
DateTime dt = startDate.Add(ts);
```

Comment: Now its nice... where is `get the timespan of A and B,`

Comment: @un-lucky I missed quoting an example, thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik I guess the output of this one is like the format of my A above.